# Does travis install npm packages globally or locally by running the tests?

Tags: npm, travis-ci

By default does travis install npm packages using package.json globally or locally? By some packages there can be differences, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Try it, see the echoed output of the install commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `npm install` command will install them locally. (If you read the log expanding the `git clone ...` part, you'll see that it `cd username/repo` then it will launch the `npm install` command).

If you need some packages installed globally, add this to your `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
- npm install -g your-package-name
```